moveit2 does not publish the /execute_trajectory topic
Kind regards, please ask if there is a topic of publishing execution trajectory sequence in moveit2?
I output the following topic information through ros2 topic list

/attached_collision_object
/clicked_point
/collision_object
/display_contacts
/display_planned_path
/dynamic_joint_states
/goal_pose
/initialpose
/joint_state_broadcaster/transition_event
/joint_states
/monitored_planning_scene
/motion_plan_request
/panda_arm_controller/controller_state
/panda_arm_controller/joint_trajectory
/panda_arm_controller/state
/panda_arm_controller/transition_event
/panda_hand_controller/transition_event
/parameter_events
/planning_scene
/planning_scene_world
/recognized_object_array
/robot_description
/robot_description_semantic
/rosout
/rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic/feedback
/rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic/update
/tf
/tf_static
/trajectory_execution_event\

I output topic information through echo. I tried ros2 topic echo /trajectory_execution_event, ros2 topic echo /display_planned_path，ros2 topic echo /panda_arm_controller/joint_trajectory
Only the /display_planned_path topic has trajectory sequence information output, but unfortunately it publishes the sequence of the plan. That is, once I plan (not execute yet) /display_planned_path the topic will publish the trajectory.
I need to communicate with the real robot and control the motion. If I publish the planned trajectory to the real controller, it will cause that if I only plan in ros2, the planned trajectory will be immediately sent to the real robot and move, but it should not move immediately.
The Real Robot movement should only be correct after I select execute in ros2. If the trajectory is only planned and published to the controller for execution, the real robot state will be inconsistent with the simulated robot state in moveit2, resulting in the robot crash.
